# Sinatra error "undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass" with a simple 'GET' request

Tags: header, get, split, sinatra

Sinatra give me this error when I do a simple 'GET' request:

```
ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass...
```

I think that the error is next to the Sinatra headers hash:

```
 response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
 response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
 response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = request.env["HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS"]
```

and this is the get method:

```
get '/login' do

   body(true.to_json)

end
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have posted incomplete error stacktrace. I suppose it may fail at `true.to_json` in case you are not loading required JSON library. Like

```
require 'json'
```

Answer (score 0):

That error usually happens when the URL returns nil. Are you sure `body(true.to_json)` returns something?